# ggplot geom_ribbon with non-deterministic ymin and ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long time series that consists of different values corresponding to the 5th, 50th, and 95th percentiles. For example, my data looks like this:

```
    Year Percentile Value
1   1990 5th 5
2   1990 50th 10
3   1990 95th 20
4   2000 5th 6
5   2000 50th 11
6   2000 95th 30
```

I'm having trouble creating a ggplot with geom_ribbon that will allow me to use the values corresponding to the 5th and 95th percentiles as ymin and ymax (respectively) across time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you convert the data to "wide" format, the 5th and 95th percentiles will become their own columns and you can then use them as `ymin` and `ymax`. So maybe something like this (where `df` is your data frame): `library(tidyverse); ggplot(df %>% spread(Percentile, Value), aes(Year, ymin=\`5th\`, ymax=\`95th\`)) + geom_ribbon()`.

Comment: Thanks. The trouble is combining that with a middle line (made of the 50th percentile).

Comment: Add this to the above code: `+ geom_line(aes(y=\`50th\`))`. Or, put `y=\`50th\`` in the `aes` statement in the main ggplot call and add `+ geom_line()`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it a new question to ask whether you can smooth the geom_ribbon lines?

Comment: New question. The natural thing to do might be something like: `ggplot(df %>% spread(Percentile, Value), aes(Year, ymin=\`5th\`, ymax=\`95th\`)) + geom_ribbon(stat="smooth", se=FALSE)`, but that  approach doesn't work when I test it on `mtcars`. You might have to calculate the smoother lines outside of ggplot and then plot them using `geom_ribbon`, but there might be a way to get `stat="smooth"` to work with `geom_ribbon`.